# NodeJS: Create resized file stream from another stream on the fly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, swagger

I need to write an upload code using NodeJS with swagger. The requirement is to create two resized files and send them to AWS S3. I can do this by:

- Save the incoming file on disk.
- Open the original file, resize(version 1) and save it on disk.
- Again open the original file, resize it(version 2) and save it on
  disk.
- Create stream1 from version1
- Create stream2 from version2
- Send both the streams to S3
- Delete residual files

What I am looking for is to create resized file from incoming stream on the fly and send them to S3 without saving anything on disk. Is this possible? Is there any module that can create resized image stream from another stream?

I can get the stream from the uploaded file as:

```
var _originalStream = new Buffer(req.swagger.params.uploadedFile.value.buffer, 'binary');
```

Next I need to use the above stream and create two streams from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sharp`](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) for that:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs    = require('fs');

let pipeline = sharp();

// temporary files (see text)
let version1 = fs.createWriteStream('output1.jpg');
let version2 = fs.createWriteStream('output2.jpg');

pipeline.clone().resize(800, 600).pipe(version1);
pipeline.clone().resize(320, 240).pipe(version2);

_originalStream.pipe(pipeline).on('finish', () => {
  console.log('done');
  ...upload files to S3 and remove temporary files...
});
```

As you can see, it can create two (or more) resized outputs directly, using `.clone()`.

Also, instead of using temporary files, you can probably use S3 streams to upload the files directly (I'm not familiar enough with S3 to provide example code for that, but it shouldn't be too difficult).

As an aside: `_originalStream` in your example isn't a stream, it's a `Buffer`. You can use those as input with `sharp` too. This will probably work:

```
let pipeline = sharp(req.swagger.params.uploadedFile.value.buffer);
```

(in that case, you don't use `_originalStream.pipe()`)